# Android video View problems

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, android-videoview

I am looking for someone who can help me how to program video view with live streaming URL.
For example any TV channel site provide the live streaming video. I want to know how use the URL link and transfer it to video view on android. so android users can play the video.
I want to know how to take the URL link to video view on android?

Answer (score 0):

These are some options you can try out.

1. Android native [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) and MediaController. A tutorial [here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/)
2. easy video player - https://github.com/afollestad/easy-video-player
3. Highly recommend [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). A nice tutorial from codelabs [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)